# Replacing previous plot on Tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, plot, weather

I'm trying to do this using Tkinter and openweathermap: include a plot in a weather app, which can tell me temperatures at different times in various cities. However, I am not able to remove the plot of the 1st city when I load temperatures of the 2nd city. **I end up having one plot on top of another, `plot.clear()` does not work here. Is there a way to replace or remove the first plot?**

Thank you.

```
def format_response_graph(weather):

    forecast = []

    for i in range(8):

            dt_txt = weather['list'][i]['dt']
            date = (datetime.fromtimestamp(dt_txt)).strftime('%d-%b %H:%M')
            temp_max = weather['list'][i]['main']['temp_max']

            final_str = (date, temp_max)
            forecast.append(final_str)

    date,max_temp = map(list, zip(*forecast))

    figure = plt.Figure(figsize = (14,2), dpi = 100)
    plot = figure.add_subplot(111)
    plot.clear()
    plot.plot(date,max_temp)

    line = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure,root)
    line.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, expand = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `root.update()` or `root.update_idletasks()` after `plot.clear()`? I'm not sure if that is going to work but you can give it a try.

Comment: Every time you call the function `format_response_graph`, a new `Figure` object is created. You should move the `Figure` creation outside of your function if you need to call it repeatedly.